# google cloud connectl local computer to network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

Is there a way to connect a local computer to google cloud network?

I have a server building ios apps on a mac mini, and would like to be able to call/make builds from google cloud VM - and copy files from local/on prem. to Google Cloud VM.

Comment: I think you can reach your goal in a few ways: **1**. enable ssh access to your mac mini to run commands remotely at the mac mini and use `scp` (or other [options](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files)) to transfer files between cloud and premises **2**. enable ssh access to your mac mini to run commands remotely at the mac mini and use cloud storage bucket [mounted](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to the VM instance to send/receive data between cloud and premises  **3** use [VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview)

Comment: Please let me know which way more suitable for your use case and I'll provide you more details.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go fo Classic VPN. I need to connect to the mac mini from Google Kubernetes Engine containers. As I understand it, I then don not need to connect from each container.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#ip-allocation) "Each Pod has a single IP address assigned from the Pod CIDR range of its node. This IP address is shared by all containers running within the Pod, and connects them to other Pods running in the cluster". The IPs of Pods are selected from the cluster CIDR range for your cluster that you can find with the command `gcloud container clusters describe my-cluster | grep clusterIpv4Cidr`. You should use it while configuring your VPN.

Comment: Do you need more details?

Comment: Thanks, I will try just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach your goal in a few ways:

1. Enable ssh access to your mac mini to run commands remotely on it and use on of the options described in the documentation [Transferring files to instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files)
    to transfer files between cloud and premises.
2. Enable ssh access to your mac mini to run commands remotely and use cloud storage bucket mounted with [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to the VM instance to [upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#gsutil)/[downlowad](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#gsutil) files between cloud and premises.
3. Use [Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview) to connect your on-premises network to the cloud.

In case of GKE cluster, you can find cluster CIDR range which contains IPs of Pods with the command:

```
 gcloud container clusters describe my-cluster | grep clusterIpv4Cidr
```

to use it while configuring VPN.

Answer (score 0):

If your local database is tabular you could use Data Express instead of an ssh tunnel, its easier to set up.

Here is the documentation and installation guide:
https://github.com/admindataexpress/dataexpress

I hope this helps you!